# Foreach loop not working in seperate class

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I am making a small experiment game in Visual Studio (C#)
I have a ManagerAndMovement class and a Collision class. The manager and movement class contains pictureboxes, which are in a list called walls, and i am trying to use that list in another class in a foreach loop to detect collision.
Here's my code:

ManagerAndMovement class (attributes and constructer)

```
public List<PictureBox> walls;
public PictureBox wall;
Collision collision;
//Collider is a picturebox on the form, it is set to public

 public ManagerAndMovement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        collision = new Collision(Collider, this);
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(GameManager_KeyPress);
        this.Controls.Add(PlayerTexture);
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(GameManager_KeyPress);

    }
```

Whole collision class:

```
class Collision
{
    PictureBox Collider;
    ManagerAndMovement m;
    public Collision(PictureBox n, ManagerAndMovement mm)
    {
        Collider = n;
        m = mm;
    }
    public bool CheckForWall(String direct)
    {
        foreach (PictureBox wall in m.walls)
        {
            if (Collider.Bounds.IntersectsWith(m.wall.Bounds))
            {
                if (direct.Equals("left"))
                    m.xWall = wall.Location.X + wall.Width;
                if (direct.Equals("right"))
                    m.xWall = wall.Location.X - wall.Width;
                if (direct.Equals("up"))
                    m.xWall = wall.Location.Y + wall.Height;
                if (direct.Equals("down"))
                    m.xWall = wall.Location.Y - wall.Height;
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

}
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
if (Collider.Bounds.IntersectsWith(m.wall.Bounds))
```

And the error is (pointing at the foreach loop and highlighting mm.walls):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It also suggested this:

> Use the "new" keyword to create an object instance

Comment: Seems like a reasonable suggestion.  You need `mm` set to a valid _instance_ of `ManagerAndMovement`.  It's not clear at all from your code where that instance should come from.  Maybe when you create the `Collision` class you set that property to the containing object?

Answer (score 0):

Change `Collision` class constructor and pass `ManagerAndMovement` instance to it

```
public Collision(PictureBox n, ManagerAndMovement m)
{
    n = Collider; //seems wrong. it should be Collider = n
    mm = m;
}
```

Comment: You might also mention that `n = Collider;` accomplishes nothing.  OP probably meant `Collider = n;`

Comment: I added that to the code (Shouldn't it be m = mm?). And the error is now in a different spot. I will update the code and showed more of the ManagerAndMovement class. T